# Как определить направление скролла на странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

Как определить направление скролла на странице?

Необходимо выполнять различные функции в зависимости от направления прокрутки.
Например, если скроллили вниз, то выполнять `down();`, а если вверх то `up();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event) {
    delta = parseInt(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail);
    if (delta >= 0) {
      $('#result').html('Вверх');
    } else {
      $('#result').html('Вниз');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: а если использовать Полосу прокрутки, то не определяет направление скролла, можно это как-нибудь исправить?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486286/176892 ответ пользователя @Invision

Answer (score 2):

Пример через событие `scroll`

```
var scrollPos = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > scrollPos){
     // down
   } else {
     // up
   }
   scrollPos = st;
});
```

Пример через событие `mousewheel`

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
      // up
    } else {
      // down
    }
});
```

Демо:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxdpzv