# Управление обработчиком

Tags: jquery

Есть обработчик `.bind`, обрабатывает от **scroll**, как выполнять другие функции если: *скроллишь вверх*, *вниз* или *не скроллишь*.

Comment: Узнал как вычислить прокрутку _вниз_ или _вверх_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо просто получить высоту `scrollTop` и сравнивнить с предыдущим значением:

```
 var point = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
var topValue = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (topValue > point) {

      callDownScrollFuntion();
    } else {
      callUpScrollFuntion();
    }
    point = topValue;

  });

function callDownScrollFuntion() {
  console.log('Scroll to down');

}

function callUpScrollFuntion() {
  console.log('Scroll to Up');

}
```

Comment: Есть вариант проще

Comment: @CbIPoK2513    > Есть вариант проще - это вопрос ? или нашли другое решение ?

Comment: вроде проще [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486264/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5?rq=1)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 , разница не большая, я написал такой пример чтобы была понятна логика работы моего примера,  + насколько помню "mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll" работает только в Moziila и Opera

Comment: Можно ли сделать функцию, если пользователь не скроллит?

Comment: Трудно понять что вы хотите сделать и понять что значит "пользователь не скроллит". вы хотите  поймать момент когда пользователь завершил скролл ?

Comment: да, именно. Задача сделать движение блока при прокрутке скролла и при этом выполнять анимацию "кручения" блока, а при остановке остановить и анимацию